# How to get the first Dataframe Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe named "s_copy". This database contains information about ships (example: name, speed, latitude, longitude and **mmsi**).

I want to group this database by **mmsi** (vessel identification number), at the moment I am using this code:

```
vectors = dict(tuple(s_copy.groupby('mmsi')))
```

Once the database is grouped, I want to be able to use the information for each **mmsi**. I have tried using indices as if it were a vector, but it doesn't work.

```
first_vector = vectors[0]
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do with the grouped data? The typical way to use `groupby` is by chaining functions like `s_copy.groupby('mmsi').mean()` or something.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `dict(tuple(s_copy.groupby('mmsi')))` acutally does, exactly? Did you try actually checking the value that you get from that? Does it meet your expectation?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Your partial description makes it harder for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  gb_df = df.groupby('mmsi')
  dfs = [gb_df.get_group(x) for x in gb_df.groups]
```

For accessing only the first group you can do like this:

```
gb_df = df.groupby('mmsi')
first_group = gb_df.get_group(gb_df.groups[0])
```